# what virtual memory manager in Linux

Tags: virtual-machine

what is the purpose of the virtual memory manager in Linux and how that differs from traditional ‘swap’ on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

You've got everything mixed up. Swap is part of Linux VM.

There are tons of pages describing memory management in Linux:

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/concepts.html

[https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html)

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/linux-memory-management/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aONIVSXiJ8

Answer (score 1):

"Virtual memory" means that things (e.g., processes) gets their own unique memory address space; generally from 0 to the maximum address that can be referenced by the CPU.  "Pages" --- chunks of memory that are managed as units --- in process' virtual address space are mapped to, among other things, pages in physical memory.  The Memory Management Unit (part of the CPU) uses the process' "page table" to translate virtual addresses referenced by running programs into the physical addresses those pages are mapped.

There does not need to be a 1:1 correspondence between virtual and physical pages; some virtual pages are unmapped, virtual pages in multiple processes can be mapped to the same physical page.

"Swapping" enables the kernel to move pages --- often infrequently used pages --- from physical memory to disk, freeing those physical pages for use by something else.  If the process tries to reference a virtual address that is mapped to a page that has been swapped to disk, then a "page fault" occurs.  The kernel will respond to the page fault by finding an available physical page, swapping the content of that physical page to disk, swapping the content of the original process' page from disk into that physical page, and updating the process' page table so that the associated virtual page is mapped to the new physical page.  At that point, the process reference to that virtual address can continue.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for this explanation